# how to add multiple value in a single list in python?

Tags: python

I have two files:

- `D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\Book1.csv`
- `D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\Book2.csv`

I want to add them in a single list-

output

```
files = ["D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\Book1.csv", "D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\Book2.csv"]
```

code-

```
        path = '/nsmnt/NS_Exec_DSHBD/output/*.csv'
        files = glob.glob(path)
        file_list = []
        for name in files:
            size = os.stat(name).st_size
            if size <= 5:
                print("file %s is empty" %name)
                log.info("file %s is empty" %name)
                file_list = file_list.append(name.split(','))
```

error:-

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    path = '/nsmnt/NS_Exec_DSHBD/output/*.csv'
    files = glob.glob(path)
    file_list = []
    for name in files:
        size = os.stat(name).st_size
        if size <= 5:
            print("file %s is empty" %name)
            log.info("file %s is empty" %name)
            file_list += name.split(',')
```

Note that name.split(',') will generate a list, append is for single values += means lista = lista + listb, in other words, add the resylt of name.split to file_list

Comment: this code giving me the given output-
['D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\\Book1.csv']
['D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\\Book1.csv', 'D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\\Book2.csv']

Comment: those are exactly the files with size <=5, what else do you want?

Answer (score 0):

```py
file_list = [i for i in glob.glob(path) if os.stat(i).st_size <= 5]
```